# How to deserialize XML starting from child element by using XStream

Tags: unmarshalling, pojo, xstream

I have an XML document that contains data like the following:

```
<Properties>
    ...
    <util>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="a">
               <externalProvider code="02">
                  <attribute key="B" value="BB"/>
                  <attribute key="CC" value="AA"/>
               </externalProvider>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="B">
                <externalProvider code="02">
                    <attribute key="paramName" value="AVV"/>
                    <attribute key="applicationName" value="DD"/>
                </externalProvider>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </util>        
    <security>
        <permissions>
            <parameter name="c">
               <externalProvider code="02">
                  <attribute key="zz" value="cc"/>
                  <attribute key="dd" value="ddw"/>
               </externalProvider>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="q">
                <externalProvider code="02">
                    <attribute key="paramName" value="as"/>
                    <attribute key="saw" value="dd"/>
                </externalProvider>
            </parameter>
        </permissions>
    </security>
    ...
</Properties>
```

I need to deserialize the XML above in order to take the elements that are in the '***permission***' tag.

My probem is that inside *'...'* there are 6 xml tags that i do not want to define as Java class and so i do not want to define all the hiearchy.

I need to use **XStream** to deserialize the object.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, wrong title. Deserialize XML